# Separation of variables to get two separate ODEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[[image]

so far I have:

u(x,t) = f(t) h(x).

h(x) df(t)/dt+ f(t) d^h(x)/dx^2=- ρ f(t) h(x)

1/f(t) df(t)/dt + 1/h(x) d^2 h(x)/dx^2 =- ρ

is my solution so far correct? I'm confused from here on, what do I do to complete this?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake in :

1/f(t) df(t)/dt + 1/h(x) d^2 h(x)/dx^2 =- ρ

The correct equation is :

$\frac{1}{f(t)} \frac{df}{dt}+\frac{1}{h(x)}\frac{dh}{dx}=-\rho$

Since $\rho$ is a function of $x$ , the separation of the functions of $x$ from the functions of $t$ leads to :

$$\frac{1}{h(x)} \frac{dh}{dx}+\rho(x)=C$$

$$\frac{1}{f(t)} \frac{df}{dt}=-C$$

where $C$= constant.

Comment: oh I see now, is that the final answer?. I thought we were supposed to solve for h(x)

Comment: No, it is not the final answer. You have to solve both ODEs and express $u=f(t)h(x)$. Note that $\int {\rho(x)dx}$ is involved in the result.

Comment: But isn't this to get the general solution?. My question ends at finding both ODEs. It says I don't need to solve it.

Comment: In that case, don't solve it. Your answer ends there.

Comment: Note : if you continue the solving, you will not find the GENERAL solution of the PDE. You will obtain a particular solution. The complete solving is more complicated and leads to : $$u(x,t)=e^{-\int \rho (x) dx}F(x-t)$$ where $F$ is any derivable function. Of course, this is not asked for in the wording of the question.

Comment: How do we know that u must be of the form  u(x,t)=f(t)h(x) ?

Comment: Say, we don't know at first : we try if it is convenient to solve the EDP. If not, one have to look for another method.